# Is the under 10mb iphone app size limit compressed?

Tags: iphone

In regards to iphone applications larger than 10mb not being able to be downloaded...

Does that apply to the compressed or uncompressed file size?

Thanks for any help

Comment: As zPesk mentioned, you do realize apps can still be downloaded if they're larger than 10 MB, right? Only not through the carrier network.

Answer (score 3):

Compressed.

*([Be careful with your 9.9MB app though](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1862941&tstart=120))*

Answer (score 0):

I believe iPhone apps can be up to 2 GB.  then 10 MB number refers to what apps can be downloaded on the cell network versus apps that can be downloaded over wifi or on iTunes on your computer.

The iPhone app Myst is much greater than 10 MB.  [Click here for link to story about app](http://www.macrumors.com/2009/05/03/cyans-classic-myst-arrives-in-app-store/)

Comment: That 2GB limit..it's for the uncompressed or already compressed app ?