# iPhone - Maximum Download 3G Size MB

Tags: iphone, size

I have heard the maximum download size for an app through ATT wireless 3G network is 10MB, anything over that size you will need a wireless router to download the app.  I am building a game with numerous images and am trying to keep it under 10MB.  Does anyone know if the xcode app's binary file cannot be 10mbs or the itunes .ipa file cannot be over 10MB?

What I mean, after I compile my application the binary file which is inside the "build" directory is at 9.9MBs.  When I add the application(game) to itunes, the .ipa itunes file that is creates is compressed down to 7.7.

If someone could give me an answer would make a big difference in my application.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The limit has also recently been raised to 20MB (see http://iphoneblips.dailyradar.com/story/apple-doubles-iphone-3g-download-limits).  Like gcamp, I assume that the limit is throttled based on .ipa file size, as that's what will actually go over the air.

50MB now (see http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57393448-37/apple-raises-3g-4g-download-limit-to-50mb/)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the binary file that you're referring to is actually your app bundle.

The 10 MB limits is on .ipa files. (Basically your app bundle zipped plus some Apple files)

Also, your question was a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849424/is-the-under-10mb-iphone-app-size-limit-compressed).